# Can't run jhipster-registry in Eclipse with dev profile, needs Git repo

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, jhipster

I just downloaded jhipster-registry v3.0.0 and built it in Eclipse with the 'dev' profile. I'm running it with the 'dev' profile as a Spring Boot app using the STS Boot Dashboard. However, it is trying to use a Git URI. I thought it was supposed to use the "native" profile and use a directory on the filesystem.

It was failing due to proxy issues, first. I commented out the git.uri property in bootstrap.yml and it complains a uri is not defined. I left it empty, but it still tries to checkout from it.

bootstrap.yml says profiles.active = dev,native

I can launch the registry using Maven from the command-line. I've never had trouble launching jHipster generated projects from Eclipse, but this one is acting different. How can I launch it and not use a Git repo?

Comment: How are you setting the dev profile?  I'm not familiar with STS but it may be changing the profile. You should be able to use `-Drun.profiles=dev,native` or `-Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,native"` to ensure Spring runs in the `dev,native` profile

Comment: I'm using the Spring Boot dashboard, where I have a Run Target setup such that Profile = dev. It works for all other Spring Boot / jHipster projects I generate.

Comment: I did get it started by adding -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= VM arguments to the run target. It wants to clone from a Git repo to start (https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry-sample-config) (maybe that's the answer if you haven't configured an internal repo)

Comment: Did you try adding `native` to where you set `dev`?  Without the native profile, it uses the git configuration instead of the local filesystem.  Other JHipster apps only use `dev` and don't have a `native` profile

Comment: I think this is the solution, set "native,dev" as the profiles to use in the run target. If you will add it as an "answer" I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using STS Boot Dashboard, make sure to include both native and dev in the profiles to use in the run target.  Use `native,dev`

Without the `native` profile, the JHipster registry's cloud config server will use the git configuration instead of the local filesystem.